# A question marked as duplicate, but is older than the linked question

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions, specific-question

I've answered an extremely common question located here: [How do you check if a variable is an array in JavaScript? [duplicate]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/767486/how-do-you-check-if-a-variable-is-an-array-in-javascript/767492#767492)

As you can see, this question was asked in 2009 and answered multiple times (including by me). If you google any phrase close to the question, this question is the one that comes up as the first result (this has been the case for years - hence the massive number of votes on it).

The question this is a "duplicate" of was actually asked a few years after. I am just curious as to the semantics of a question asked in 2009 in good faith as being a duplicate of one asked after-the-fact. It seems to me the linked question was a duplicate of the first, not the other way around.  What is the appropriate etiquette here? Should I vote to reopen the original?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The question with less valuable content should be closed as a duplicate of the question with more valuable content.  The dates either question was asked is irrelevant.

If the duplicate question has quality answers that would add value on top of the answers to the canonical question, the questions can be merged by a moderator.